# PHP Foreach - How to list only one row?

Tags: php, html, foreach

I have a multidimensional array, Im using a foreach loop to output the results, however, I only want to show one result - the second set of values in the array

Currently the output looks something like this:

```
<tr><td>Price without tax:</td><td>100</td></tr>
<tr><td>Price total:</td><td>120</td></tr>
```

I only want the second row, I tried adding

```
<?php if($total['title'] != true) { ?>
```

But then I got an error, the page couldn't load.

If I delete the first column it will delete the left text (Price without tax and price total), if I delete second column it will delete the right text (100 and 120)

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="right"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</b></td>
      <td class="right"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: you can use print_r or var_dump to look inside the array you have, then you can echo out the correct index - http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uh, you looking for this?

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="right"><b><?php echo $totals[1]['title']; ?>:</b></td>
      <td class="right"><?php echo $totals[1]['text']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You do seem to be confusing 'rows' and 'columns', I'm not *entirely* sure I understood your question correctly.

Comment: couldn't have been more easier than this :). +1

Comment: It is an opencart script and I am trying to modify it. I have price without tax in first row and total price in second row. I want only to show total price.

Comment: You are genius! Thanks :) I am learning PHP so this cleared up some confusion in my head! :)